# python minidom does not close <xml tag>

Tags: python, xml, minidom

I'm experiencing a strange behaviour using minidom. I run the following code:

```
import os
import sys
from xml.dom import minidom
def generateReleaseXMLFile():
    modelPath = "%./model/"
    # Create the parser
    xsydoc  = minidom.Document()
    # Create the element ScriptModelVersion
    scriptModelVersion  = xsydoc.createElement('ScriptModelVersion')
    # Assign all the attributes
    scriptModelVersion.setAttribute("Major", "1")
    scriptModelVersion.setAttribute("Minor", "2")
    scriptModelVersion.setAttribute("Patch", "3")
    scriptModelVersion.setAttribute("ReseaseDate", "2011-05-20")
    # Append the root to the document
    xsydoc.appendChild(scriptModelVersion)
    # Create the file descriptor
    fdesc = open(modelPath+"Release.xml", "w")
    # Write the file
    fdesc.write(xsydoc.toprettyxml())
    # Close the file
    fdesc.close()
    print xsydoc.toprettyxml()

generateReleaseXMLFile()
```

It generates the following output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<ScriptModelVersion Major="9" Minor="0" Patch="1" ReleaseDate="2011-05-20"/>
```

whithout the xml tag closure.
I really have no idea about why it's keeping the document open. Did anyone experienced the same problem? Or am i simply forgetting somethink really obvious and i simply canot see the problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `<?xml ... ?>` is not a tag, but the [XML Declaration](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-tipdecl/index.html). There is not need to close it, your document is in perfect shape.

Comment: you right! so stupid... it was an hour i was getting crazy... i did not even tought about this. i open other document i created and of course is as you said. shame on me! :)

Answer (score 1):

Your XML is valid :
Have a look at : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_Schema_%28W3C%29

You do not need to close declaration.